# Test Name and Test Output in AssemblyCleanup

Tags: c#, mstest

I am completely new to unit testing but I will try my best to explain the problem.

We have Junit Project and maybe more than 7K tests. We sometimes have change in one file which triggers more than 20 failures which is worrisome. So is there anyway I can manipulate test output ?

My Idea (don't know if it's feasible): Create a class with [AssemblyInitialize()] and [AssemblyCleanup()]. Now is it possible to capture test name and test output in [AssemblyCleanup()] ?

If not could anyone suggest better idea through which I can cycle through test outputs and manipulate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Test name and Test Result using TestContext

Just instantiate it at the top of your class and then it will be accessible in the methods below. This is how I use it for my selenium tests for reporting.

```
       public class TestBaseChrome: WebDriver
      {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
         //Do stuff here
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
          var testName = TestContext.TestName;
          var testResult = TestContext.CurrentTestOutcome.ToString();

          //Do what you need
        }
      }
```

You might also have issues with the Assembly Methods, as they are not inheritable, so may not be able to create a separate class that uses them.

These are my findings and how I get the name/results of the tests.

Hope this helps.